# Can't send a message from background page to content script at Chrome Extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, message, content-script

I have this at my Background page:

```
function go(){
chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
  chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {greeting: "hello"}, function(response) {
    console.log(response.farewell);
  });
});

}

go();
```

And this at my content script:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    console.log(sender.tab ?
                "from a content script:" + sender.tab.url :
                "from the extension");
    if (request.greeting == "hello")
      alert(request.greeting);
  });
```

I expected the alert to launch as I enable the app, but nothing is happening. Am I missing something?

EDIT: The manifest.json:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "Naming",
  "description": "any",
  "version": "1.0",

  "permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "activeTab",
    "https://google.com.br/"
  ],

 "background": {"scripts":["background.js"]},

  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "js": ["CLAWS_Content_Script.js", "jquery.js"],
      "css": ["CLAWS_Content_Script_CSS.css"],
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"]

    }
  ],

  "web_accessible_resources": [
        "CLAWS_Sem_Imagens.html",
        "icone_XVermelho.png"
  ]


}
```

The content script gets loaded, because other funtions it provides works perfectly. There are no errors at the console.

Comment: @wOxxOm sorry, I don't know hot to debug it...but the other info. were added : )

Comment: Oh, do you know that when you re-enable the extension, the content script  declared in manifest.json isn't magically reinserted? You should reload the webpage as well.

Comment: @wOxxOm That was a good guess, but unfortunatelly didn't work : ) and, based on what I've learned about debugging in chrome extensions over the last five minutes, I could say that, Maybe, the listener in the content script is never called...

Comment: And, oh, I'm really able to pass some messages from the content script to the background page...

Comment: Can you upload the extension zip somewhere and link it here?

Comment: @wOxxOm  I can't post the original extension, but I can mimic the issue here: http://www.4shared.com/zip/_BPbYRRKce/Extension.html

Comment: try this: setInterval(function(){go();}, 1000); in the background page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The message is sent when the browser starts or the extension is enabled but at that moment there is no active content script to receive it. Similarly, when you reload the webpage, your background page isn't reloaded, so no message is sent, and consequently, nothing is received.

If you really want `the alert to launch as I enable the extension`, then inject the content script manually via [chrome.tabs.executeScript](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-executeScript), in which case you don't need `"content_scripts"` section in manifest.json.

Comment: Thanks! It was helpful!